# how to implement search by multiple params

Tags: performance, search, data-structures

Multiple params received from request:
 - domain
 - GEO
 - referer
 - other params
Database table looks like that:

```
domain   | geo    | referer | utm | option_id |
---------|--------|---------|-----|-----------|
test.com |        |         |     | 1  
test.com | us     |         |     | 2  
test.com | us     | ref.com | 12  | 3   
test2.com| us     |         |     | 4
```

For example i received some request with params:

```
domain=test.com  
geo=us  
referer=ref.com  
utm=12
```

If i do a query:

```
select option_id from table where domain='test.com' and geo='us' and referer='ref.com' and utm='12';
```

It gives me full match result only option_id = 3
But i need to get all the options, for every match with domain and geo.
option_id = [1,2,3]

How to solve the problem in performant way, maybe the solution is not SQL database. I need to search in highload system in realtime. 
Help will be useful, thank you.

The query that satisfy selection will be:

```
select option_id from table where domain='test.com' and geo='' and referer='' and utm=''
UNION 
select option_id from table where domain='test.com' and geo='us' and referer='' and utm='' 
UNION 
select option_id from table where domain='test.com' and geo='us' and referer='ref.com' and utm='12'
```

But it is slow, i know that exist simple and performant solution. Maybe without SQL database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the options that match at least 1 of the params you should use OR instead of AND

```
select option_id from table where ( domain='test.com' OR geo='us' OR referer='ref.com' OR utm='12' );
```

Comment: I expand my example with more data. If i will use 'or' that it will give me option 4 in result for another domain

Comment: Maybe i'm not fully understanding your goal.

You want all the lines that match the domain and the geo, but you are saying you also want the line with option_id = 1, that has no geo

Comment: Think null value is equal to any

Comment: oh i see

then try this

`select option_id from table where ( domain='test.com' OR domain is null) AND (geo='us' OR geo is null);`

Answer (score 0):

```
select option_id from table where domain LIKE '%test.com%' and geo LIKE '%us%' and referer LIKE '%ref.com%' and utm like '%12%';
```

i'm not test this code but you must use like, it will search component with pattern.